# SQLite FMDB creating table - beginner iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

I think this is a simple question but I didnt find the answer in the FMDB git page.
When you use the command:

```
[database executeUpdate:@"create table T_table(name text primary key, age int)"];
```

does FMDB or SQLite make some kind of verification to see if the table already exists?

Can I call this method in my class initializer without creating more than one table?

Sorry if stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you give the `CREATE TABLE` command to FMDB, it internally converts it into corresponding SQLite query (for which you don't have to worry).

As per the official documentation given on SQLite's website, it states:

`"It is usually an error to attempt to create a new table in a database that already contains a table, index or view of the same name."`

So, if you try to create another table with the same name, SQLite will throw an error saying:

```
create table test_table (test_no NUMBER, test_name TEXT); //Table created

/* Now, try creating the table again */
create table test_table (test_no NUMBER, test_name TEXT);
```

You will get the following error.
**Error: table test_table already exists**

So, SQLite checks for the existence of the table, it won't allow another table with the same name.

Again, you can refer to the documentation to get more details.

**Source** http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Answer (score 15):

Another solution is to change your query to:

```
create table if not exists test_table (test_no NUMBER, test_name TEXT);
```

or, you can check for the existence with:

```
select sql from SQLITE_MASTER where name = 'test_table'
```

And see if you get any results back.

Answer (score 0):

```
var databasePath = String()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let filemgr = FileManager.default
        let dirPaths = filemgr.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                    in: .userDomainMask)

        databasePath = dirPaths[0].appendingPathComponent("contacts.db").path

        if !filemgr.fileExists(atPath: databasePath as String) {

            let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

            if contactDB == nil {
                print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            }

            if (contactDB.open()) {
                let sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT)"
                if !(contactDB.executeStatements(sql_stmt)) {
                    print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
                }
                contactDB.close()
            } else {
                print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            }
        }
        save()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func save()
    {
        let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

        if (contactDB.open()) {

            let insertSQL = "INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name, address, phone) VALUES ('\("abc")', '\("abc")', '\("1234")')"

            let result = contactDB.executeUpdate(insertSQL,
                                                  withArgumentsIn: [])

            if !result {
                //status.text = "Failed to add contact"
                print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            }
            else
            {
                getData()
//                status.text = "Contact Added"
//                name.text = ""
//                address.text = ""
//                phone.text = ""
            }
        } else {
            print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }
    }

   func getData()
    {
        let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

        if (contactDB.open()) {
          //  let querySQL = "SELECT address, phone FROM CONTACTS WHERE name = '\(name.text!)'"
            let querySQL = "SELECT ID,address, phone FROM CONTACTS"

            let results:FMResultSet? = contactDB.executeQuery(querySQL,
                                                               withArgumentsIn: [])

            while results?.next() == true
            {
                let id = results?.string(forColumn: "ID")
                //(forColumn: "address")
                let phone = results?.string(forColumn: "phone")
                print(phone ?? "")
                print("\(id)")
                //status.text = "Record Found"
            }
//            else
//            {
//                print("")
//               // status.text = "Record not found"
//               // address.text = ""
////phone.text = ""
//            }
            contactDB.close()
        }
        else
        {
            print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }




    }

}
```